# Seg Fault usando strcat e strcpy

Tags: c, string

Esse é meu código:

```
char CodificarCesar(char *texto_nao_codificado[256], int chave){

char alf[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\n','\0'};
char mensagem_codificada[256], mensagem_original[256];

memset(mensagem_codificada,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_codificada));
memset(mensagem_original,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_original));
strcpy(mensagem_original,texto_nao_codificado);

for(int i=0;i<strlen(mensagem_original);i++)
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(alf);j++){
        if(mensagem_original[i]==alf[j]){
            mensagem_codificada[i]=alf[j+chave];
            break;
        }else if(mensagem_original[i]==toupper(alf[j])){
            mensagem_codificada[i]=toupper(alf[j+chave]);
            break;
        }else if(isspace(mensagem_original[i])){
            mensagem_codificada[i]=" ";
            break;
        }//else space
    }//for j

strcat(mensagem_codificada,"\n");
memset(mensagem_original,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_original));

return mensagem_codificada; }
```

Estou fazendo um programa de criptografia simples usando cifra de césar, porém em duas situações estou recebendo segmentation faults do além, aparentemente, ambos os casos apresentando que a função strcat está envolvida sendo que em nenhum deles ela sequer é chamada.

Vale notar que nas situações em que recebo falha de segmentação são situações em que strings com espaço são entradas.

No primeiro caso é no retorno da função, depois que todas as string foram processadas corretamente.

No segundo caso é no processamento das strings, quando o debugger chega na linha que contém alguma chamada à função strcpy (dentro dos if's de equivalência com algum caractere do alfabeto).

Não consegui achar nenhum caso similar pesquisando, nem consegui ter alguma ideia do que causa ou pode estar causando isso.
Qualquer ajuda seria bem vinda.

[EDIT] Obrigado @Jefferson Quesado por avisar que estava usando `strcpy` para chars

[EDIT2] Falha de Segmentação só ocorre com strings com espaços

Comment: Você faz uma chamada de `strcpy` para copiar um único caracter? `strcpy(mensagem_codificada[i],alf[j+chave]);`?

Comment: Sim, revisando meu código eu estava achando esquisito fazer `mensagem_codificada[i] = alf[j+chave]` e mudei para  `strcpy´, mesmo que estivesse funcionando, para ver se esse não era o erro, mas fazendo isso só criei outro erro.

Comment: Eu imaginei que a falha de segmentação viesse dessa chamada, mas já existia sem fazer isso, certo?

Comment: Sim, já existia, tanto é que isso foi um chute de solução que só gerou uma segunda falha de segmentação separada da primeira.

Comment: Achei um possível bug/bug latente: se eu passar a string `"zorro"` com a chave de cifra 2, qual deve ser o resultado? `alf[25 + 2]` vai apontar para um possível endereço não alocado. Pode ser que esse não seja **O** erro, mas talvez possa dar dor de cabeça

Comment: Outro problema, acho que esse mais sério: `alf` não é uma string nulo-terminada. É um vetor de 27 posições, sendo as 26 primeiras as letras de A a Z minúsculas, e a posição 26 a quebra de linha. Além dessa posição, estamos em endereço inválido para esse objeto. Como `alf` não é nulo terminado, você vai ter problemas chamando `strlen(alf)` e [salvando a princesa](https://toggl.com/programming-princess)

Comment: Quanto ao primeiro bug, isso eu já tinha anotado para arrumar, porém esse problema se mostrou mais sério; quanto ao segundo, eu nem sequer havia reparado nisso, vou arrumar imediatamente; obrigado por ajudar com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maior parte das alterações que fiz foram guiadas pelos avisos do compilador, algo que nunca devemos ignorar.

Vou tentar cita-los para que seja clara a lógica que guiou nas alterações:

> warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type

Que se refere a esta linha:

```
strcpy(mensagem_original,texto_nao_codificado);
```

O problema aqui é que o `texto_nao_codificado` não foi declarado com o tipo certo e por isso os dois tipos não jogam. `texto_nao_codificado` foi declarado como `char *texto_nao_codificado[256]` que é do tipo `char**` em vez de `char*` ou `char[]` como era suposto.

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Nesta linha:

```
mensagem_codificada[i]=" ";
```

Se `mensagem_codificada` é um array de `char`s então cada posição é um `char` logo não pode ser atribuída a uma posição uma `string` e sim um `char`. Por isso `" "` deverá ser `' '`

> function returns address of local variable

No `return`:

```
return mensagem_codificada;
```

Aqui o compilador indica que não é suposto devolvermos endereços de variáveis locais pois estas são alocadas em *stack* que é libertado após a função retornar fazendo com que o acesso depois da função seja invalido. Em vez disso a variável deve ser alocada no *heap* com `malloc` para que persista após a função terminar,

Logo a criação desta variável:

```
char mensagem_codificada[256];
```

Deve passar a ser:

```
char* mensagem_codificada = malloc(256*sizeof(char));
```

> return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Este ultimo tem ainda a ver com o retorno e com o tipo retornado não jogar com a declaração. Está-se a retornar `char*` quando a declaração:

```
char CodificarCesar(char texto_nao_codificado[256], int chave){
```

Indica `char`. Basta alterar a declaração para que indique `char*` também:

Assim:

```
char *CodificarCesar(char texto_nao_codificado[256], int chave){
```

Existe ainda um outro problema subtil que é quando troca uma letra por outra, aqui:

```
mensagem_codificada[i]=alf[j+chave];
```

Pode-se dar o caso de passar o tamanho de `alf` acedendo a uma posição de memoria invalida. Por exemplo tem a letra `z` e quer avançar `5`, vai ficar fora do array. Para contornar esta situação pode utilizar o operador `%` (modulo) com o tamanho do array para garantir que dá a volta e fica sempre dentro do mesmo:

```
mensagem_codificada[i]=alf[(j+chave)%26];
```

Depois de fazer todas as alterações o código ficar então assim:

```
char* CodificarCesar(char texto_nao_codificado[256], int chave)
{

    char alf[]= {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','\n','\0'};
    char mensagem_original[256];
    char* mensagem_codificada = malloc(256*sizeof(char));

    memset(mensagem_codificada,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_codificada));
    memset(mensagem_original,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_original));
    strcpy(mensagem_original,texto_nao_codificado);

    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(mensagem_original); i++)
        for(j=0; j<strlen(alf); j++)
        {
            if(mensagem_original[i]==alf[j])
            {
                mensagem_codificada[i]=alf[(j+chave)%26];
                break;
            }
            else if(mensagem_original[i]==toupper(alf[j]))
            {
                mensagem_codificada[i]=toupper(alf[(j+chave)%26]);
                break;
            }
            else if(isspace(mensagem_original[i]))
            {
                mensagem_codificada[i]=' ';
                break;
            }//else space
        }//for j

    strcat(mensagem_codificada,"\n");
    memset(mensagem_original,'\0',sizeof(mensagem_original));

    return mensagem_codificada;
}

int main(){
    char msg_orig[] = "abc";
    printf("%s", msg_orig); //abc
    printf("\n%s",CodificarCesar(msg_orig, 2)); //cde

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/9yfinV)

Comment: Só um detalhe, tentar codificar `Zorro` com a chave 1 retornaria `[pssp`. Para ter o comportamento circular convencional da criptografia de Cezar (`z` com chave 1 mapeia para `a`), deveria ter uma verificação adicional

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Refere-se ao exemplo final que eu dei ? Ou ao que já vinha da pergunta?

Comment: A essa linha: `mensagem_codificada[i] = mensagem_original[i]+chave ;`, que você colocou na edição. Fiz uma leitura muito superficial da sua resposta, isso acabou se destacando

Comment: Sobre o módulo, creio que o tamanho do vetor não deveria ser 24, mas 26 (27 considerando o `'\n'`, que eu não consideraria), visto que temos 26 caracteres. `'z'` chave `0` está traduzindo para o índice `25 % 24 == 1`, portando `'b'`. Como a chave é `0`, não deveria ter mudanças de valor

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Agradeço de facto o comentário. Sim sobre o módulo estava a agora a reparar que `24` não estava correto. E quanto ao exemplo de codificação que dei não é foi circular, o que fará sentido ser para coincidir com o exemplo da pergunta. Já irei ajustar nesse sentido.